# How to choose how often Apache Airflow scheduler updates a DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

As stated in [Apache Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval), I can control how often a DAG is updated by setting configuration variable `min_file_process_interval` in your `airflow.cfg` file:

> **min_file_process_interval**
>
> Number of seconds after which a DAG file is parsed. The DAG file is parsed every min_file_process_interval number of seconds. Updates to DAGs are reflected after this interval. Keeping this number low will increase CPU usage.

**However, I didn't find any clue or best practice about which value should I set for `min_file_process_interval`.**

#### Example

My DAG changes once a day. By default `min_file_process_interval` is set to 30 seconds. It means most of the time updating DAG is useless: as long as DAG doesn't change, updated DAG and previous DAG are the same. It consumes resources and generates logs. But if I update DAG only once a day, do I risk to run wrong DAG if DAG changes after the daily DAG update or the DAG is also updated just before run ?

**What value for `min_file_process_interval` should I set in this case ?**

**EDIT:** As stated in [Elad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68195159/6807769) responding to a previous version of this question, dynamic DAGs should be avoided. However, If I have dynamic DAGs, how to choose `min_file_process_interval`?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different things.
`min_file_process_interval` means how often Airflow scan the `.py` files and update the DAG within Airflow. Consider that when you deploy new `.py` file Airflow needs to read it and create it in the metastore database - so the setting is about how often it happens.

For your use case the DAG code should not be updated every day - In fact it should not be updated at all. It should just run everyday. Your dag just need to be able to handle the correct file per date. You code can be something like:

```
from airflow.providers.ftp.sensors.ftp import FTPSensor

with DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    # Waits for a file or directory to be present on FTP.
    sensor_op = FTPSensor(
        task_id='sensor_task',
        path='/my_folder/{{ ds }}/file.csv', #path to your file in the server
        fail_on_transient_errors=False,
        ftp_conn_id='ftp_default'
    )
    
    # Operator to process the file
    operator_op = SomeOperator()

    sensor_op >> operator_op
```

In that DAG it will start a run everyday - the first operator is sensor thus if the file for that day isn't present the workflow will wait until it appears only once it appear the workflow will continue to the 2nd operator which should process the file.
Note that the `path` parameter of FTPSensor is templated. This means you can use [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) like `{{ ds }}` this will give you a path that contains each day date like:

```
/my_folder/2021-05-01/file.csv
/my_folder/2021-05-02/file.csv
/my_folder/2021-05-03/file.csv
```

You can also do `path='/my_folder/{{ ds }}.csv'` which will give:

```
/my_folder/2021-05-01.csv
/my_folder/2021-05-02.csv
/my_folder/2021-05-03.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @Elad ! I simplified my example use case before asking my question, but by doing that I made you answer the wrong question. I agree with you, I should avoid dynamic DAG and Airflow provides solution for my simplified example. I will remove all references about files in my question. But in the case I have a dynamic DAG updating every day, what should I keep in mind when setting `min_file_process_interval ` ? If dynamic DAGs are bad, why updating them every 30 seconds per default ?

Comment: dynamic dags are ok. In your question you mentioned a design where the code of the dag itself is changing every time - this is something else. Dynamic dags are just a code that from 1 py file you can create multiple dags. As for your question the only thing you should consider that relates to min_file_process_interval is not to make expensive work outside of operators scope. This means for example no database calls in top level code. For example don't make task_id depended on data you get from a database.